LoRa-02 SX1278 won't receive a message from another Ra-02
I have 2 LoRa-02s set up on 2 different computers, and they are both on 433 MHz and it seems like one of them isn't working and I am quite certain it's the receiver.
Transmitter code:
import machine
import utime
import time
import _thread
import ustruct
import sys

import uLoRa as lora

cspin = machine.Pin(5,machine.Pin.OUT)
dio0 = machine.Pin(6,machine.Pin.IN)
rst = machine.Pin(7,machine.Pin.OUT)
spi = machine.SPI(0,
                  baudrate=2000000,
                  polarity=1,
                  phase=1,
                  bits=8,
                  firstbit=machine.SPI.MSB,
                  sck=machine.Pin(2),
                  mosi=machine.Pin(3),
                  miso=machine.Pin(4))
led = machine.Pin(25,machine.Pin.OUT)

lora_init = lora.begin(spi,cspin,rst,dio0,433)

if lora_init:
    print("LoRa OK")
    
else:
    print("LoRa Failed!!")
    
while True:
    if lora_init:
        lora.beginPacket()
        data = "Hello!!"
        enc_data = data.encode()
        packet = bytearray(enc_data)
        es = lora.dataPacket(packet)
        lora.endPacket()
        print("Packet Sent")
        led.value(1)
        time.sleep(0.25)
        led.value(0)
    time.sleep(10)

Receiver:
import machine
import utime
import time
import _thread
import ustruct
import sys

import uLoRa as lora

cspin = machine.Pin(5,machine.Pin.OUT)
dio0 = machine.Pin(6,machine.Pin.IN)
rst = machine.Pin(7,machine.Pin.OUT)
#rst = None # uncomment if you are not using reset pin
spi = machine.SPI(0,
                  baudrate=1000000,
                  polarity=1,
                  phase=1,
                  bits=8,
                  firstbit=machine.SPI.MSB,
                  sck=machine.Pin(2),
                  mosi=machine.Pin(3),
                  miso=machine.Pin(4))

cspin.value(1)

lora_init = lora.begin(spi,cspin,rst,dio0,433)

if lora_init:
    print("LoRa OK")
else:
    print("LoRa Failed!!")
while True:
    if lora_init:
        packet_size = lora.parsePacket()
        if packet_size > 0:
            print("Received Packet")
            while lora.available() > 0:
                print(chr(lora.read()))
            print(" with RSSI ")
            print(lora.packetRssi())
        #time.sleep(1)

It is all connected as follows:
VCC: 3.3V
GND: GND
SCK: GPIO2
MISO: GPIO4
MOSI: GPIO3
NSS: GPIO5
RST: GPIO7
DIO0: GPIO6
Thanks in advance!
I have tried putting the baudrate the same, and still did not work.
